# How to do the prediction of user action?

Tags: prediction

I have a dataset, which is based of a log.The data is as following:

```
   bid LOGIN UPDATE_BILLING CREDITCARD_APPROVED CREDITCARD_DECLINED UPDATE_MONTHLY_BUDGET CREATE_AD UPDATE_AD_BID UPDATE_AD_BUDGET UPDATE_AD PAUSE_AD
1   -1     0              0                   0                   0                     0         0             1                2         0        0
2    1     0              0                   0                   0                     0         0             1                2         0        0
3   -1     0              0                   0                   0                     0         0             2                3         0        0
4    1     0              0                   0                   0                     0         0             3                3         0        0
```

bid is the label. 1 means increase bid, -1 means decrease. the other column is the user actions. For each time a user change the bid, I count how many different actions this user did during the past one day. If the action happens once, it will be 1. AS you can see, most of the table is 0,because this action does not happen.

I was asked to predict the bid will increase or decrease. I feel it is not predictable. I train a simple naiveBayes model to see what happens. the accurency is only 0.48.

Do you think the increase/decrease is predictable? do you have any suggestion about how to do the prediction?